# Calling Python from VBA - returning Python function value

Tags: python, vba

I call Python script from VBA. The structure of this Python script is a single function without anything else:

```
def myFunction():
    # do stuff
    return stuff_output
```

I know that this function works properly, because if added, `print(myFunction())` generates correct output (JSON response) in command line.

In my VBA code 'RetVal` is always a 4 digit integer value. Perhaps Python function isn't even executed?

Which code and how should I fix to make it work? I would appreciate a solution which is close to my current code and without external libraries if possible.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunPython()

    Dim RetVal
    Dim scriptPath As String

    scriptPath = "C:\Users\Rychu\Desktop\python\myPythonScript.py"
    RetVal = Shell("C:\Python36-32\python.exe" & " " & scriptPath, vbHide)

    If RetVal = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't run python script!", vbOKOnly
    Else
        Debug.Print RetVal
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't claim that to be a solution. I just wanted to let you know that works partially. However, taken that out so that any efficient answer comes along @Ryszard Jędraszyk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any direct way to transfer value returned by Python function, so I handled it by saving Python result to text file on Desktop and reading + deleting the same file with VBA.

Important things are:

1. `shellObj.Run` unlike `Shell` allows to set a Boolean parameter to wait for return to `True`, so that the rest of VBA code doesn't try to get data from text file while there isn't any created yet.
2. If text file doesn't have a full file path specified, only a file name, Python won't create text file in directory in which Python script is located, as it happens when I run script through command line or Visual Studio. Apparently when called from VBA, Python has a different perception of default directory and it isn't a directory of VBA file either.

Here is my Python code:

```
def myFunction():
    # do stuff
    return stuff_output

import os

f = open(os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop") + "\myTemp.txt","w")   #create a new text file on Desktop in write mode
f.write(str(myFunction()))  #write output to created text file 
f.close()   #close file object
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunPython()

    Dim shellObj As Object: Set shellObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim tempTxtPath As String

    Const scriptPath As String = "C:\Users\Rychu\Desktop\python\myPythonScript.py"
    Const pythonPath As String = "C:\Python36-32\python.exe"
    tempTxtPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\myTemp.txt"

    shellObj.Run pythonPath & " " & scriptPath, vbHide, True

    Debug.Print (getTextAndDelete(tempTxtPath))

End Sub

Function getTextAndDelete(filePath) As String

    Dim fileNum As Long
    Dim myData As String

    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Binary As #fileNum

    myData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #fileNum, , myData
    Close #fileNum

    Kill filePath

    getTextAndDelete = myData

End Function
```