# Return Selenium Python value to VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, selenium

I'm new to VBA but have some experience on Python, and I'm working on a project that needs to **scrape** a webpage in order to get some info. When this info is fetched, it must fill a worksheet cell.

I've found some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915099/calling-python-from-vba-returning-python-function-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516875/return-result-from-python-to-vba) (mainly the second link) but guess that I'm missing something, because the Python shell window blinks quickly on the screen and then it does nothing. I've used a `MsgBox` to "print" the return value and got nothing as well, like if the script wasn't running.

*Disclaimer*: I'm not using `Shell.Run` because I want to receive my Python script return value on VBA, so I can put cell by cell accordingly.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim codigo As String
    codigo = InputBox("Leia o QRCode.", "...")
    
    'Data
    Dim dateString As String
    code1 = Now
    
    'Hora
    Dim hourString As String
    code2 = Hour(Now)
    
    'Modelo
    Dim theShell As Object
    Dim theExec As Object
    Dim runPath As String
    Dim modelName As String
    Dim model As String
    Dim theOutput As Object
    
    Set theShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    runPath = "python " & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\get_modelo.py " & "'" & codigo & "'"
    Set theExec = theShell.Exec(runPath)
    Set theOutput = theExec.StdOut
    modelName = theOutput.ReadLine
    
    While Not theOutput.AtEndOfStream
        modelName = theOutput.ReadLine
        MsgBox modelName
        If modelName <> "" Then model = model & modelName
    Wend
    
    Set theShell = Nothing
    Set theExec = Nothing
    Set theOutput = Nothing

    'Tem que ver alguma forma de conseguir
    'o link ao ler o QRCode, ou teremos
    'que gerar o link no nosso script também
    
    'Lote
    
    Worksheets("database").Range("A2").Value = dateString
    Worksheets("database").Range("B2").Value = hourString
    Worksheets("database").Range("C2").Value = model
    
End Sub
```

My Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import webbrowser
import sys

def get_modelo(address_string):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.set_window_position(-10000, 0)
    driver.get(address_string)

    model = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="top90"]/h1')
    return model.text

print(get_modelo(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Why not just use python to write to an Excel workbook/csv? Is this part of a larger VBA script? There is also selenium basic for VBA chrome automation. Finally, have you verified that info is not available by xhr?

Comment: have you tried to run the python script independently ... ??    Also to check if the python function is called, i will set a print inside the function to be sure the call goes through.